# opacity of color passed as props Styled component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, css-in-js

I was trying to edit the opacity of color passed as props, I can do it with sass like that

```css
background: rgba($primary, 0.2);
```

I try to do the same with the styled-component, but is not working.

```js
`background-color: rgba(${(props) => props.theme.primary}, 0.8);`
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix it but not what I was waiting for, you need to use costume property.

```js
 primary = "96, 113, 201";

`background-color: rgba(${(props) => props.theme.primary}, 0.8);`
```